# JS populated div content to PHP array without any html tags

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to pass from a div content populated by JS to a PHP array and inject that array in a wordpress posts loop.

I managed to get an array with the desired values BUT there is an html tag around which is breaking the loop.

I thought that by adding a `preg_match_all` around that would fix the problem but for some reason the array ends up empty.

I have pasted just below my current state. Currently i'm getting an empty array.

I think this might be coming from the fact that the JS must populate the div after the php has run...

Would any of you have an idea on how to do this? Many thanks in advance. If you need anymore info please do not hesitate.

```
  <?php
  $rule = '#<div class="sessionWrongsIDs">(.+?)</div>#';
  $content = '<div class="sessionWrongsIDs"></div>';
  preg_match_all( $rule, $content, $matches);
  print_r( $matches[1] );

  $args = array(
  'post__in' => $matches[1],
  'post_type' => 'qcm'
  );
  $posts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ( $posts as $p ) : ?>
  <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
  <?php echo the_title();?><br/>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**EDIT 1:** Following @FluffyKitten comment, here are some additional info
Using the following:

```
  <?php
  $rule = '/<[^>]*>/';
  $content = '<div class="sessionWrongsIDs"></div>';
  preg_match( $rule, $content, $matches);
  print_r( $matches );
  ?>
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] =>
1237,1227,1238,1232
```

And if you inspect that array you can see a div around the values like so:

```
Array ( [0] =>
<div class="sessionWrongsIDs">1237,1227,1238,1232</div>
```

To use the array in a wp loop I require a format like so `arrray( 1237, 1227, 1238, 1232 )`

**EDIT 2**: Following @jibsteroos comment, about `strip_tags()`. The following is returning nothing. Probably because the `<div class="sessionWrongsIDs"></div>` content is javascript generated.

```
  <?php
  $rule = '/<[^>]*>/';
  $content = '<div class="sessionWrongsIDs"></div>';
  preg_match( $rule, $content, $matches);
  print_r( strip_tags( $matches[0] ) );
  ?>
```

**EDIT 3**: Following @FluffyKitten 2nd comment, here is the JS side. I'm using local storage to save the post ID and display it in a hidden div on the frontend. My thaught was to use the generated content (posts IDs) to generate a new query. But i've not been able to do it successfully .

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
  var sessionWrongsIDs = [];

  for ( i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++ ) {
    keys = window.localStorage.key( i );
    if ( keys.slice( 0, 3 ) === 'QCM' ) {
      sessionWrongsIDs.push( JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem( keys ) ) );
      $( '.sessionWrongsIDs' ).html( sessionWrongsIDs.join( ',' ) );
    };
  };
  $( 'input[name=answSel]:radio' ).click( function() {
    if ( $( 'input[name=answSel]:checked' ).val() == 0 ) {
      var sessionWrongsIDs = [];
      localStorage.setItem( $( '.currentTitle' ).html(), $( '.currentID' ).html() );

      for ( i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++ ) {
        keys = window.localStorage.key( i );
        if ( keys.slice( 0, 3 ) === 'QCM' ) {
          sessionWrongsIDs.push( JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem( keys ) ) );
          $( '.sessionWrongsIDs' ).html( sessionWrongsIDs.join( ',' ) );
        };
      };
    };
  } );
} );
```

Comment: have you tried using `strip_tags()` - [demo](https://3v4l.org/8fCuR)

Comment: Hi, Yeah I tried it, but as the content is returned empty, I can't verify if it's working

Comment: Its hard to know when we can't see it in action. When it was working except for the surrounding div, what code were you using and what value were you getting (including the div)? If we look at what you had got working, we might be able to come up with a different way around the problem.

Comment: I was posting my answer when you were editing your question with edit 2.... looks like that won't work then! :)

Comment: Can you show us the js code that is being used to generate the content? How are you geting the value into the `$content` variable? What do you get if you `var_dump( $matches );` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: `var_dump( $matches[0] );` returns the following `string(30) "1237,1227,1238,1232` and with the inspect tool `string(30) "<div class="sessionWrongsIDs">1237,1227,1238,1232</div>`. `var_dump( $matches[0] );` returns an empty string.